# encryption and decryption in Sqlite database?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I want to create a different project in .Net. That will be used for encryption and decryption of SQLite database. I am using this code for encryption, which is working:

```
SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=c:\\test.db3");
cnn.Open();
cnn.ChangePassword("mypassword");
```

But i want to decrypt the database and for that i am using this code for decryption:

```
SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=c:\\test.db3;Password=mypassword");

cnn.Open();
cnn.ChangePassword(null);
```

But the code  cnn.ChangePassword(null); shows the below error:

```
   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ChangePassword(byte[])' and 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ChangePassword(string)'
```

I found this useful link for the above code

http://gater3.rssing.com/chan-3257136/latest.php

but I don't where i am doing mistake.

Needs help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do try this first

```
cnn.ChangePassword(String.Empty);
```

then

```
cnn.ChangePassword((String)null);
```

or

```
cnn.ChangePassword(default(byte[]));
```